# Minimal WinSDK features for bazel

Tags: bazel

I'm installing Bazel so I can install [mediapipe](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/install.html) for Python on Windows 10. It says in the [Bazel requirements](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/windows.html):

> The Windows SDK contains header files and libraries you need when
> building Windows applications.

So I downloaded WinSDK and found out that the full installation requires 3.4GB. Is there a minimal set of features that I need to install from WinSDK for Bazel to work, so I can avoid installing the whole 3.4GB? This is the list of the WinSDK features:

[image: WinSDK Features]

- Windows Performance Toolkit
- Debugging Tools for Windows
- Application Verifier For Windows
- .NET Framework 4.8 Software Development Kit
- Windows App Certification Kit
- Windows IP Over USB
- MSI Tools
- Windows SDK Signing Tools for Desktop Apps
- Windows SDK for UWP Managed Apps
- Windows SDK for UWP C++ Apps
- Windows SDK for UWP Apps Localization
- Windows SDK for Desktop C++ x86 Apps
- Windows SDK for Desktop C++ amd64 Apps
- Windows SDK for Desktop C++ arm Apps
- Windows SDK for Desktop C++ arm64 Apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Windows SDK for Desktop C++ x86 Apps` was enough (it auto selects its dependency packages as well).